# CSS for Rotating text in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have text inside a list item (`<li>`), and I want to rotate it 270 degree. In FireFox, Safari, Chrome, and Opera we have found direct methods, but in the case of IE, there is no direct support. However, there are some filters like `matrix` and `BasicImage`: I tried them, but I am not getting anywhere.

For example, I am doing something like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

It is only rotating the first character of all list items

Comment: Surely you want to rotate the whole list 270 degrees? Rather than just one list item.

Comment: ya and one more thing i forgot that for styling list element iam using multiple classes (4) in first i am giving some background image and color in second iam giving color to text in third iam giving these transition effect working fine in all browser except IE fourth one is empty

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but it may be because you've only allowed enough width for each `<li>` to display just the first character or two.  It displays correctly without rotation because the text is properly overflowing the width of the `<li>`.  I'm coming across a similar issue where IE will only rotate the text that is visible by the container's width.

If you can increase the width of each `<li>` without it messing your layout, then do that and see if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

See:

[Element Rotation (CSS Tranformations)](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/)

> CSS3 has introduced a number of transformation and animation capabilities, which some have suggested are out of place in CSS. Nonetheless, there is a way to mimic element rotation in Internet Explorer, albeit in a limited fashion.
>
> #### THE SYNTAX
>
> To rotate an element 180 degrees (that is, to flip it vertically), here is the CSS3 syntax:
>
> ```
> #rotate {
>     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
>     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
> }
> ```
>
> To create the exact same rotation in Internet Explorer, you use a proprietary filter:
>
> ```
> #rotate {
>     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
> }
> ```
>
> The value for the rotation can be either 1, 2, 3, or 4. Those numbers represent 90, 180, 270, or 360 degrees of rotation respectively.